# How to solve for the zeros of $3x^4 - 7x^3 - 12x^2 + 12x + 11$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I’ve tried to see if a rational factor would work from $q/p$, but that hasn’t worked.

I tried grouping and then factoring but that does not work either.

I do not know any further methods that I could use since it doesn’t seem like I could use the quadratic formula or completing the square.

Comment: This does not seem to be very easy to handle. See [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3x%5E4+-+7x%5E3+-+12x%5E2+%2B+12x+%2B+11+%3D0) for example.

Comment: There is a [quartic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) to solve for the roots; otherwise, I think any solution will just involve some clever manipulations (although WA's solution doesn't seem to indicate there are nice numbers to be expected).

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to (partially) factor this polynomial?

Comment: how do you know you have correct coefficients?

Comment: The comment of @WillJagy is based on the idea that normally, pre-calculus students are not given math problems that require that the quartic equation be used.  Further, if Wolfram Alpha doesn't indicate a *simple* factorization, that suggests that the quartic equation is required.  The situation suggests that the problem solver has made a mistake in analysis, and that the problem composer intended that the problem solver be left with a different quartic equation (where the coefficients were different).  Plausibly, the intended quartic equation would have a simple factorization.

Comment: @Clayton We have $3$ degree roots in the exact form. But in general, the clever manipulations usually reduce the degree of polynomial from $4$ to $2$, I think.

Comment: @lonestudent: Your comment doesn't make sense to me. We have a general formula to determine the roots of a fourth-degree polynomial, however unsightly it may be (I like to it on Wikipedia)

Comment: @Clayton I know general formula and also solutions methods. But, you didn't understand, what I mean.

Comment: @lonestudent: Which is why I said that your comment doesn't make sense to me and you've offered no further explanation. Upon reading it again, I don't see how your comment actually adds any value. The ``clever manipulations'' refers to grouping of various types (perhaps reducing it to a quadratic in another variable or leading to factorizations straightaway). In any case, the direct method of grouping terms is non-obvious and so I described the process as clever.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: You can convert the equation such that factorization becomes easier:

$3x^4-7x^3-12x^2+12x+11=0$

rewrite as:

$x^4-\frac 73 x^3-\frac 4x^2+4x+\frac {11}3=0$

Let y=kx :

$y^4-\frac 73 \cdot \frac{y^3}{k^3}-4\cdot \frac{y^2}{k^2}+4\cdot\frac yk +\frac{11}3=0$

let $k=3$:

$y^4-7y^3-36y^2+108y+297=0$

Now you can factor and tranform equation to:

$y^2(y^2-7y-18)-18y^2+108y+297=0$

$y^2(y-9)(y+2)-9[2(y-9)(y+3)+21]=0$

$(y-9)[y^2(y+2)-18(y+3)]=1\times 9\times 21$

Now equate factors on both sides; for example:

$y-9=1\Rightarrow y=10\rightarrow x=\frac{10}3=3.3$

$y^2(y+2)-18(y+3)= 9\times 21$

apply similar method to find more solutions.

Wolfram gives $x=-1.345, -0.69, 1.28, 3.08$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a well-known method to solve any fourth degree polynomial equation.

It is called [Descarte's Method](http://ky.matyc.org/The%20Quartic%20Formula%20%20(Descartes).pdf).